# How should i load a file in python efficiently using all my cpu power?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I decided to create a python code to encrypt my data a while back, when i am half way through, i decided to do a performance test, and the result is horrible, like only 430kB/s encrypting speed. Opening System monitor showed that only 1 thread of my 8C16T processor is being used by my program.

After I try temporary deleting the encrypting part in my code, it was only like 10kB/s faster. So i analyzed the code and found out this part of code

```
with open("10MB.test", 'rb') as f:  
    byte = f.read(1)
    if(i == 0):
        test = (str("".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in byte for ch in line])))
        i = 1
        while byte != "":
            g = g + 1
            byte = f.read(1)
            a = str("".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in byte for ch in line]))
            test = test + a
```

runs very slow,  and system monitor shows that it only uses one thread of my cpu . Is there a way to utilize all thread of my CPU to make this run faster?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
realsr = ""
test = ""
i = 0
m = 0
g = 2
j = 0
ti1 = 0
ti2 = 0
ea = raw_input("Please Input Your First Password: ")
print "You Entered:",ea
eb = raw_input("Please Input Your Second Password: ")
print "You Entered:",eb
ec = raw_input("Please Input Your Third Password: ")
print "You Entered:",ec
ed = raw_input("Please Input Your Forth Password: ")
print "You Entered:",ed
ee = raw_input("Please Input Your Fifth Password: ")
print "You Entered:",ee
ef = raw_input("Please Input Your Sixth Password: ")
print "You Entered:",ef
eg = raw_input("Please Input Your Seventh Password: ")
print "You Entered:",eg
eh = raw_input("Please Input Your Eighth Password: ")
print "You Entered:",eh
ti1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
with open("10MB.test", 'rb') as d:
    j = len(str("".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in d for ch in line])))
with open("10MB.test", 'rb') as f:  
byte = f.read(1)
if(i == 0):
    test = (str("".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in byte for ch in line])))
    i = 1
while byte != "":
    g = g + 1
    byte = f.read(1)
    a = str("".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in byte for ch in line]))
    test = test + a
    if(j != len(test)):
        temp1 = int(a,16)
        if(m == 0):
            temp1 * ea
        if(m == 1):
            temp1 * eb
        if(m == 2):
            temp1 * ec
        if(m == 3):
            temp1 * ed
        if(m == 4):
            temp1 * ee
        if(m == 5):
            temp1 * ef
        if(m == 6):
            temp1 * eg
        if(m == 7):
            temp1 * eh
while len(test) >= j:
    with open("clone.test", 'wb') as k:
        k.write(test.decode("hex"))
    ti2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    print "done!"
    print test
    print (ti2-ti1)
    print ti1
    print (ti2)
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You read your file one byte at a time: `f.read(1)`. This is a horrible idea. You should read as much as you can safely fit in the memory (perhaps the whole file, if the memory size permits) and then do encryption.

Comment: i originally intended to encrypt the file byte by byte, but i think i should have a try at encrypting whole file

Comment: You can still encrypt it byte by byte. Just don't read it byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access all your CPU cores you will need use Pythons [Multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process).

And from the docs;

> In multiprocessing, processes are spawned by creating a Process object
>   and then calling its start() method. Process follows the API of
>   threading.Thread. A trivial example of a multiprocess program is

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: That is true but with the OP having an i9 processor I think he will get more speed with multiprocessing than multi threading

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "byte = f.read(1)" in order to load 1 byte from the file, use this :

```
content = f.read()
for byte in content:
    # your code
```

With this method, you could won in speed execution because you don't stop reading between all bytes. You only access the file once.